# Is there an analytic solution to this equation? $a+b\sin(x)+c\tan(x)=0$

Tags: trigonometry

Here is the equation which should be solved for $x$:

> $$
> a+b\sin(x)+c\tan(x)=0
> $$
>
> where $a$, $b$, and $c$ are constants.
>
> Is there an analytic solution, or at least an algorithm to approximate it for any given set of constants?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the universal substitution $t=\tan(x/2)$ gives
$$
a+b\cdot\frac{2t}{1+t^2}+c\cdot\frac{2t}{1-t^2}=0
$$
So you just need to clear denominators and [solve the quartic](https://planetmath.org/QuarticFormula).  (OK, the last link is a joke.  You should solve it using the algorithm from Galois theory instead of a single nasty formula.)

Comment: @Somos: you get a quartic: $(1-t^2)(1+t^2)=1-t^4$ will appear with the $a$.